# Draw a line between view and shadow

Tags: android, canvas, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop in Android now. I want to draw a line between View and its DragShadow. It should looks like this:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOXAT.png)

I have already tried to implement it in two different ways:

- First, I tried to update the end of the line when DragEvent.ACTION_LOCATION occurs. But it's not smooth, because frequency of this event is not appropriate.
- My second approach was to create custom DragShadowBuilder but I couldn't draw a line on Canvas of DragShadow because it has fixed size and follow cursor.

How could I implement this properly?

Comment: Why not just use the touch events to update the canvas. You know that the drag shadow will follow the touch events so between the ACTION_DRAG_STARTED and ACTION_DRAG_ENDED (or appropriate for your circumstance) listen to the touch events to get a smooth update.

Comment: I've tried it. But it seems I can't receive onTouchEvent while drag.

Comment: Have you tried OnTouch rather than onTouchEvent

Comment: Yea, I tried. But it gives the same result. I receive neither onTouch nor onTouchEvent while drag.